# WooCommerce Subscriptions with Account Funds payment hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

I'm running WooCommerce with Subscriptions and Account Funds plugins.

I'm needing to add funds to a user's profile every time a subscription payment is processed.

WooCommerce Subscriptions has the `processed_subscription_payment` action to hook into.

Account Funds creates a user meta field called `account_funds`.

Here is the code I've come up with so far, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm using PayPal Sandbox to test it, but I think they're having problems right now. Either that or my code is bad.

```
add_action('processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);

function custom_process_order($order_id) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;

    $amount = $order->get_order_total();
    $funds = get_user_meta( $myuser_id, 'account_funds', true );
    $funds = $funds ? $funds : 0;
    $funds += floatval( $amount );
    update_user_meta( $myuser_id, 'account_funds', $funds );

}
```

I'm trying to pull the user's ID from each processed subscription payment, then add the funds to their account.

Here's the Account Funds file I referenced to help create my function: http://pastebin.com/Teq8AXz8

And here's the Subscriptions documentation I'm referencing: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/

What do I seem to be doing wrong?

Comment: According to the subscription docs `$order_if` is not one of the two parameters passed to the processed hook.

Comment: Oh, duh! It already passes the `$user_id`, so I don't need to get the user ID through the `$ordfer_id`. I'll see if this works.

Comment: @helgatheviking I've got this somewhat working. When $amount is set to an integer, it will add that amount to the account_funds meta field. Here's an example: http://pastebin.com/u7dpk4Ct. However, any time I try and pull order info (I need to get the total of the order), I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_total() on a non-object`. I'm trying to call `wc_get_order()` to fetch the order ID and then the total from that, however it keeps shooting that error. Am I close? Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/vHD0DWyT

Comment: Please edit your question instead of linking to pastebin. That error means that `$order` is not an object, so you can't run `get_total()` on it .You trying to run `wc_get_order($order_id)` but you don't have an order id.

Comment: Do you need to add the full order's total or the subscription's price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$subscription_key`](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/data-structure#subscription-key) is a unique identifier that is made up of the subscription’s product ID and the ID of the order in which the subscription purchased. Therefore you can split that string into 2 useful variables. Untested, but try the following:

```
add_action( 'processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_process_order', 10, 2 );

function custom_process_order( $user_id, $subscription_key ) {

    if( class_exists( 'WC_Account_Funds' ) ){

        // split subscription key into order and product IDs
        $pieces = explode( '_', $subscription_key);
        $order_id = $pieces[0];
        $product_id = $pieces[1];

        // get order total
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $amount = floatval( $order->get_total() );

        // alternatively get product price
        // $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        // $amount = $product->get_price();

        // add account funds
        WC_Account_Funds::add_funds( $user_id, $amount );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

@helgatheviking helped get me extremely close. The only thing that wouldn't work was `get_order_total()` and `WC_Account_Funds::add_funds($customer_id, $amount)`.

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
add_action('processed_subscription_payment', 'custom_process_order', 10, 2);

function custom_process_order($user_id, $subscription_key) {

    // split subscription key into order and product IDs
    $pieces = explode( '_', $subscription_key);
    $order_id = $pieces[0];
    $product_id = $pieces[1];

    // get order total
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $amount = $order->get_total();

    // get current user's funds
    $funds = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', true );
    $funds = $funds ? $funds : 0;
    $funds += floatval( $amount );

    // add funds to user
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_funds', $funds );

}
```

Thanks @helgatheviking!

Comment: Could you test whether `add_funds` works if I copy and paste better and pass it the correct user id? Will edit in a minute.

Comment: Hello, I have a very similar case to this. Must this above code be placed in the functions.php file of the theme? It's difficult to test for this since it only fires when the subscription renews.

Comment: @user57513 Did this work on the initial purchase as well as the renewals or just the renewals. I'm trying to do it for both the initial purchase and the renewals